# Why make an eruv with just a single-owner courtyard? (Eruvin 85)

Tags: eruv-chatzerot, maseches-eruvin

<sub>My kid asks:</sub>

The [Bavli, *Eruvin* 85 *amud* 2](https://www.sefaria.org/Eruvin.85b.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) just after the *mishna*, says that if a location is such that its resident's not being part of an *eruv chatzeros* doesn't prevent the *eruv* from taking effect for others, then that location is an unsuitable place for those others to place their *eruv*. It gives one exception: the gatehouse of a privately owned courtyard. Others can create an *eruv* without the gatehouse resident, but can nonetheless place their *eruv* in the gatehouse. But the courtyard is privately owned! Why would it need an *eruv* at all if the *eruv* doesn't include the gatehouse resident?

Answer (score 1):

According to Rashi (whose explanation of the Mishna you are following), the gemara is teaching two separata halachos regarding the gatehouse to the private courtyard:

1. One who lives **only** in the gatehouse does not need to be included in the eruv.
2. One who lives in a regular house in the courtyard, but also owns a gatehouse, may place the eruv in the gatehouse.

Comment: But in #2 why is an _eruv_ needed? There's one resident in the courtyard.

Comment: The eruv joins this courtyard with ajoining courtyards, and allows carrying between them.